# how can i get the database address on the map in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-maps

For the corresponding id I want the marker to point to the database address of that id. How can I do? Where can I get the code? I am using JS, Asp.Net, Sql server

Answer (score 0):

Thats a simple thing, You have to create a database table that include Latitude and Longitude of you adress.. and if you need to have a simple English Adress then you have to use Google Geolocation API, after storing the adresses,
then for every entry in the Locations Table do following things
**In .cs**

```
 public StringBuilder locs = new StringBuilder(); //globalVariable
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (Location l in loc)
                            {
                                longitude = l.Yaxis; //where Yaxis is a variable in class Location to store  longitude
                                lattudei = l.Xaxis; //where Xaxis is a variable in class Location to store  Latitutde
                                sb.Append(string.Format(
                                "['{2}','{0}','{1}','../Img/Icons/Vehicles/icon_{2}.png'],",
                                lati, lon, imgurl);
                            }
    locs.Append(sb.ToString());
```

**.aspx**

```
 <script>
  var map;
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 5,
                    minZoom: 4,
                    maxZoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.03105543, -39.44091797),

                });
    var locations = [<%=locs %> ];
     var markers=[];
     for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                        map: map,
                        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(locations[i][3] + "?" + new Date().getTime(), 
                            null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,15)),
                        id: locations[i][0],


                       });
                    markers.push(marker);
    </script>
```